# Custom authentication firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm making a react native app using firebase, for logging in im using email and pass authentication. But, is there a way to login in using username and password?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/username-password-auth for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, firebase *does not* provide username and password for login.

If you really need to use username+password (why though?), the solution is to setup it yourself using [firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You save the username and password yourself in firebase, and the function read and match the inputted data from firebase. If matched, you create [custom firebase auth token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

Beware though, don't expose sensitive data publicly, be sure to set the database to reject all read/write request from user (only allow it from your function)